# How to reduce weight's bit or change to lower bit's type in tensorflow by using MNIST?

Tags: python, tensorflow, training-data, mnist, 8-bit

I'm doing CNN model compression,and trying to reduce the weight's bit to get relation between bit's length and accuracy. But when I use Tensorflow Website's method to change the weight's Type of CNN,it came out an error :

" TypeError : Value passed to paramter 'a' has DataType int8 not in list of allowed value : float16 , float32 , float64 , int32 , complex64 , complex128  ".

It seems that weight's cannot be other Dtype. But I read some papers like that https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.02551.pdf . it is possible to reduce weight's bits to 6bits , 4bits , even lower bit.

my code is here (ignore import somethings):

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/",one_hot=True)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.int8,[None,784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]),tf.int8)
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]),tf.int8)

y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W)+b)
#the error come out with "y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W)+b)"
```

It is just a standard tensorflow official code and Just changing the Dtype of the variables. Also I have tried tf.cast , but it still come out the error .

```
tf.cast(W,tf.int8)
tf.cast(b,tf.int8)
```

Can anyone tell me how to overcome this situation?  Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Please add the example of your code as well as your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow doesn't allow numbers with less than 16 bits. Less than 16 bits would be impractically anyways, because assuming you use 8 bits (4 bits for integer, 4 bits for decimal), the lowest possible decimal number would be 0.0625 (1/16 -> 4 bits only have 16 different numbers).

The paper you cite uses 16 bit numbers, were the 16 bits are split in 8-8, 10-6, and 14-2 bits (The first ones being the decimal bits). It also rounds the variables and then converts them to the above bit-distributions, instead of just cutting off the variables without rounding.

---

**Update:** I did a little digging, and it practically doesn't make much of a difference if you're using `float16` or a 14-2 fixed bit-distribution:

- Lowest `float16` decimal number: **0.0000610352**
- Lowest decimal number for a or a 14-2 fixed bit-distribution: **0.00006103515625**

> So I would suggest, you just use `float16` instad of fixed
>   bit-distributions, and just use the stochastic rounding algorithm,
>   described in the paper.

---

**Update 2:** I trained the MNIST dataset with both `float32` and `float16`. The `float16` network performed almost the same as the `float32` network. The network had two hidden layers with each 1000 neurons and `tf.nn.relu` as the activation function. I used the standard tensorflow `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer` optimizer with a learning rate of 0.1. As the cost function I used `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`. The network was trained over 120 epochs, each 600 steps with a batch-size of 100. The test accuracy of the `float16` network was **98.189997673**, while the `float32`test accuracy was **98.1599986553**.

**Some interesting links:**

> - [GTC talk on mixed precision training](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2017/presentation/s7218-training-with-mixed-precision-boris-ginsburg.pdf)
> - [NVIDIA fork of caffe](https://github.com/NVIDIA/caffe)

**Update 3:** I think implementing mixed precision in tensorflow would be hard, because you'd have to write custom handling for back-propagation. The tensorflow team is working on implementing nativ half precision already. Meanwhile, I think the best way to implement this is by using caffe, where native mixed precision is already implemented (at least in the [nvidia branch](https://github.com/NVIDIA/caffe)). See [this ticket](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4589).

Comment: This is not an answer. Could you add it as a comment in the question?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't comment on questions jet.

Comment: I undid the downvote and I commented below the question.

Comment: Hi  !  Markus Schwer 
Thanks for answering =)
I try that too , but still having the same error =(

Comment: Yes, float16 can work ! But I want to know whether it can be done by using lower bits . Maybe i need to modify tensorflow's file to use self-define function?  After all , thanks for your answering =)

Comment: I think so ! Thus, I try to  find a way converting them to above bit-distributions and make it work ! However , this is the point I don't know how to realize. =(

Comment: I'm trying to implement the paper now too. I'll keep you posted if I find anything new.

Comment: Thank you so much ! if I have any new progress , I will update my question =)  thanks ! ! !

Comment: I think I found a way to implement stochastic rounding in tensorflow. I'll update my answer again, when I successfully tested it.

Comment: Thanks ! ! ! I am trying other way too.  Wish we find the way to realize. =)

Comment: I implemented the stochastic rounding, as described in the paper. I implemented in pure python and tensorflow.

Comment: Thanks !! I have try them for a while , but  there is an error coming up.

Comment: As the paper you cited focuses on hardware implementations, I would suggest you look at this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.03740.pdf

Comment: I think the paper help a lot when using float16. thank you =)

Comment: I just tested the performance of float16 and float32 networks on mnist. I did no special rounding or anything like that and the networks nearly performed identically.

Comment: Hi Markus Schwer ~ the link you pasted is helpful to me !! Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP is concerned with reducing the precision of weights but not inclined towards doing the same on the implementation level, I think this could help:

You can lower the precision (by approximating the high-precision values) of the weights by writing your own custom layer in Keras: https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/

You can find an example of binary weights model here: https://github.com/DingKe/nn_playground/blob/master/binarynet/binary_layers.py

You will have to edit the `call()` method of your layer and approximate the weights to the required no of bits. See below:

````
```
def call(self, inputs):
    low_precision_kernel = reduce_precision_by_round_off(self.kernel)
    <--- Use the low precision kernel get the outputs --->
    return outputs

```
````

The self.kernel is defined in `build()` call of the custom layer.